# почему часть страницы, подгружаемая через ajax, иногда пропадает

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Загружаю кусок страницы через ajax. такой код:

```
function refresh()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "tickets.php",
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#tickets").html(result);
            aligntickets();
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "items.php",
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#items-wrapper").html(result);
        }
    });
    console.log('Page has been refreshed!');
}   
refresh();
```

первая страница загружается каждый раз, а вторая, каждые пять обновлений страницы не загружается.если запустить функцию потом заново, то подгрузится, однако, если этот блок подгрузился сразу, тогда при обновлении функцией он не пропадает.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

ps Если перейти на саму страницу `items.php`, то таких проблем не бывает.

pss вот код  `items.php`:

```
<?php 
include ('link.php');
include ('core.php');

$cg = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");

$players = array();
$offers = array();
$itemscounter = array();
$i = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `userid`,`id`,`offerid` FROM `games_history` WHERE `game_id` = '$cg' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($offers[$i] != $row["offerid"])
    {
        $i++;
        $itemscounter[$i] = $row["id"];
        $offers[$i] = $row["offerid"];
        $players[$i] = $row["userid"];
    }
    else
    {
        $itemscounter[$i] = $itemscounter[$i]."|".$row["id"];
    }
}
echo "<table class='items-table'>";
for($i = 1; $i <= count($itemscounter); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr class='items-table-row'>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `avatar`,`name` FROM `users` WHERE `steamid`='$players[$i]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<td><img class='items-avatar' src='".$row['avatar']."'/></td><td class='images-table-name-collumn'><span>".$row['name']."</span>";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`value`) AS `sum`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `games_history` WHERE `offerid`='$offers[$i]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "</br><span class='items-counter'>".$row['count'].itemsnumber($row['count'])."</span></td><td><span class='items-value'><img class='items-arrow' src='assets/images/little-arrow.png'/>".round($row['sum'],2)."$</span></td>";
    $items = explode('|',$itemscounter[$i]);
    foreach ($items as $it) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `item`,`color`,`image` FROM `games_history` WHERE `id`='$it'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<td class='items-table-img-column'><img class='items-img' src='http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/".$row['image']."' title='".$row['item']."'/></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

function itemsnumber($count)
{
    if($count == 1)
    {
        return " вещь";
    }
    elseif ($count < 5) {
        return " вещи";
    }
    else
    {
        return " вещей";
    }
}
?>
```

функция `aligntickets()`:

```
function aligntickets()
{
    var tickets = document.getElementById('tickets-wrapper');
    var width = tickets.children.length*(125);
    tickets.style = 'width:'+width+'px;';
}
```

Comment: Дебаггер в network что показывает?

Comment: @Invision, в том то проблема, что ничего не показывает, кроме `Page has been refreshed!`

Comment: Ну так у вас Page has been refreshed выводится еще до выполнения ajax запроса (сервер еще не ответил). Если не отрабатывает `console.log(err);`, значит либо `result` пустой, либо элементов `tickets` или `items-wrapper` нет

Comment: @Invision, логично предположить, что это так, но если обновлять `items.php` такой проблемы нет. Непонятно почему эта проблема возникает 1 раз из пяти, а может и того реже

Comment: Для понимания нужно открыть вот эту волшебную штуку https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/imgs/network-panel.png с вкладкой XHR, посмотреть статусы и все встанет на свои места. Если не поможет, напиши в нужном месте (в js) `debugger;` и займись отладкой.

Comment: @Invision, в обоих случаях написано, что загружается 738 Байт с этой страницы. Получается проблема именно в присваивании кода элементу

Comment: Нужно смотреть конкретный запрос (у тебя их 2), посмотреть состояние (Status код), кликнуть на запрос, проверить результат выполнения. Если внутри все ок но содержимое не обновилось, то дебаж методы success.

Comment: что делает `aligntickets`?

Comment: @Invision, задает размер блоку, сверху написал

Comment: @Invision, попробовал убрать `aligntickets`, ничего не изменилось

Comment: `refresh();` (скрипт) отрабатывает в шапке или подвале?

Comment: @Invision, сразу после задания функции и когда приходит соответствующая команда через сокет

Comment: Если вызов `refresh();` обернуть в `$(function() { refresh(); });` проблема решена? (для вариации "после задания функции")

Comment: @Invision, если выполнять после загрузки страницы `window.onload = refresh();` ничего не меняется

Comment: @Invision, да, это помогло, а в чем прикол то, я не понимаю? Объясни,   если не трудно.

Comment: Достаточно было поставить брекпоинт в success и посмотреть наличие элементов. Добавил ответ, не забудьте отметить как "правильный" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо обернуть вызов функции `refresh` в

```
$(function() {
  refresh();
});
```

Функция будет выполнена когда закончится формирование `DOM` дерева при начальной инициализации страницы.
Проблема заключалась в том, что элементы `#tickets` и `#items-wrapper` еще не существовали в `DOM` дереве. Даже с учетом задержки ответа от сервера, `DOM` еще не успевал сформироваться, по этой причине метод не всегда срабатывал.